# Fail to extract Zip Demographics Data using get_zip_demographics() function in ChoroplethrZip package

Tags: r, choroplethr

I am trying to get the zip demographics data of the year 2015. When I tried the codes below, an error message returns.

```
library(devtools)
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.4.0')

library(choroplethrZip)
df_zip_2015 = get_zip_demographics(2015,5)
```

When the data tries to read in, I first got a few NAs introduced by coercion warnings, but then an error message returns

```
Error in choroplethr:::convert_acs_obj_to_df("zip", age, 1) : 
argument "include_moe" is missing, with no default
```

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are installing choroplethrZip version 1.4.0. However, if you go to the choroplethrZip [github page](https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethrZip) you will see that the latest version is actually 1.5.0.

When I run this code:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')

library(choroplethrZip)
df_zip_2015 = get_zip_demographics(2015,5)
```

I do not get the error you describe.

Comment: I still have the same Error message after I installed the newest choroplethrZip package 1.5.0 from github. I'm using a Mac, will try to run the codes on a different computer tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just restart the computer and R session next day, and the same codes worked...

Not sure if this is the reason, but this time, the above codes are the first ones that I ran. Maybe the previous problems were from calling choroplethr package in some other places... I literally have no idea why it started working all of a sudden.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Since this issue is now solved, please accept the answer :)

Comment: oh yeah, your answer was very helpful. Sorry I am new to stackoverflow, and I forgot to accept your answer yesterday.